# Pythonで相関関係がある２つの要素（AとB）があるときに、 Aが分かっていてBにいくつか分からない数がある場合の、分からない数の求め方を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Pythonで相関関係がある２つの要素（AとB）があるときに、
Aが分かっていてBにいくつか分からない数がある場合の、分からない数の求め方を教えて下さい。

Comment: 抽象的で短い文章だと何のことか分からないのでは？ 対象の分野は何でそれのどういったデータか、使っているパッケージ/ライブラリ/ツールは何か、相関や分かっている/いないというのは何でどう表されるか、具体的な問題/課題は何か、望ましい結果の例等はあるか？ といったことの詳細を追記した方が良いと思われます。

Answer (score 0):

いろいろな求め方があると思います。
例えば相関関係がわかっている場合、計算式で求められます。
相関関係がB=A+1であれば、Aに1を加えればBが求まります。
相関関係がブラックボックスであり、A、Bともに整数であれば、Bを0から1ずつインクリメントし、
A==相関関係計算(B)となるようなものを見つける方法があります。